# why does window.scrollTo work cache scrollTo value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm working on this project with vue, there's a list of posts that shows on the users homepage and when show full post is clicked on i replace the list of posts showing with an expanded view of that single post.

The challenge comes when the user goes back to see the list of posts, the page scrolls back to the top regardless of where they've scrolled to previously.

I want the page to go to exactly the point they were in before they clicked on view full post.

What i did was to store the value of the current scroll position when show full post is clicked and then when the back button is clicked use window.scrollTo to go to that position.

This works for the first time, but for consequent times it always goes to the position for the first time.

I'm thinking this is a problem with vue caching the function or something but i'm not sure on how to go about it.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <post-list @showFullPost="showFullPost($event)" v-show="!showingFullPost"></post-list>
    <full-post @goBack="showAllPosts" v-if="showingFullPost"></full-post>
  </div>
</template>

<script> 
   export default{
     data: function(){
         return {
            currentHeight: 0,
            showingFullPost: false
         }
     },
     methods:{
       showFullPost(post){
          this.currentHeight = window.scrollY;

          //other code
       },
       showAllPosts(){
         //some code

         window.scrollTop(0, this.currentHeight); //this only works the first time and subsequently goes to the position of the first time
       }
     }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Will the component be rendered again? If the component is rendered again, `currentHeight` is initialized.

Comment: @Dev.DY No the component is not re-rendered, because at some point i got to console log the value of `currentHeight` and even checked the value in my vue dev tools and everything looks fine till the `window.scrollTo` function

Comment: I think it's a matter of time for rendering. 'scrollTo' seems to be running before page DOM is created. Try to run 'scrollTo' after page DOM is created. For example, 'nextTick'

Comment: This should have been the case but it works the first time you click on a post.                             But for subsequent times it goes back to the position of the first post you clicked on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

I don't know why this works but using a setTimeout function fixed the problem.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  window.scrollTop(0, this.currentHeight);
}, 20);
```